# Postfix: Connect; Immediate Disconnect

Tags: postfix

I'm trying to get a PHP mailing script (using PEAR) working on my web server connecting to my remote Postfix box, and each time  the script executes, I get no errors in either my PHP output or my Postfix logs, but no email is sent.

The corresponding log items for the request are this:

```
Nov 19 10:15:34 mailer postfix/smtpd[2611]: connect from xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx.static.cloud-ips.com[xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx]
Nov 19 10:15:34 mailer postfix/smtpd[2611]: disconnect from xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx.static.cloud-ips.com[xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx]
```

I know my Postfix server is working correctly, since I have other applications that can send mail to it just fine (and they're relayed correctly).

I also know that this script is working since I can copy it verbatim (except for changing the location of the PEAR libraries) to another web server (on HostGator) and it connects and sends the email fine.

I wish I could get some sort of error message to give me some kinda clue as to where to go from here, but I've got no error messages: just a connection followed by an immediate disconnection. I am **only** having this problem trying to send mail from this specific web server.

What's causing this and what can I do to fix it?

The Web Server I'm having issues with is running Ubuntu 8.04.2 LTS (hardy).

---

**postconf**

```
alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases
alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases
append_dot_mydomain = no
biff = no
broken_sasl_auth_clients = no
config_directory = /etc/postfix
inet_interfaces = all
mailbox_size_limit = 0
mydestination = test.com
myhostname = test.com
mynetworks = 66.109.25.xxx, 127.0.0.0/8
myorigin = /etc/mailname
notify_classes = bounce, 2bounce, delay, policy protocol, resource, software
readme_directory = no
recipient_delimiter = +
relayhost = 
smtp_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtp_scache
smtpd_banner = $myhostname ESMTP $mail_name (Ubuntu)
smtpd_recipient_restrictions = permit_mynetworks,reject_unlisted_recipient,reject_non_fqdn_sender,reject_unknown_sender_domain,permit_sasl_authenticated,reject_unauth_destination,check_policy_service inet:127.0.0.1:60000,reject
smtpd_sasl_auth_enable = yes
smtpd_sasl_local_domain = test.com
smtpd_sasl_security_options = noanonymous,noplaintext
smtpd_tls_cert_file = /etc/ssl/certs/ssl-cert-snakeoil.pem
smtpd_tls_key_file = /etc/ssl/private/ssl-cert-snakeoil.key
smtpd_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtpd_scache
smtpd_use_tls = yes
```

**PHP code**

```
<?php

  require_once('Mail.php'); // loads in PEAR Mail package; correct path

  $mailer_params['host'] = 'test.com';
  $mailer_params['port'] = 25;
  $mailer_params['auth'] = true;
  $mailer_params['username'] = 'test@test.com';
  $mailer_params['password'] = 'test123';

  $mail =& Mail::factory('smtp', $mailer_params); 

  $headers = array(
    'From' => 'test@test.com',
    'Reply-To' => 'test@test.com',
    'Subject' => 'test'
  );

  $message = "whatever";

  $email = 'test@test.com';
  try {
    $sent_ok = $mail->send($email, $headers, $message);
  } catch (Exception $e) {
    echo "Exception: ". $e->getMessage();
  }

?>
```

**tcpdump**

```
tcpdump: verbose output suppressed, use -v or -vv for full protocol decode
listening on eth0, link-type EN10MB (Ethernet), capture size 65535 bytes
13:24:00.771272 IP 173-45-233-xxx.static.cloud-ips.com.58994 > mailer.xxx.com.smtp: S 4010320431:4010320431(0) win 5840 <mss 1460,sackOK,timestamp 3028083892 0,nop,wscale 5>
    0x0000:  4500 003c 469b 4000 3f06 c5c4 ad2d e92b  E..<F.@.?....-.+
    0x0010:  ad2d ebd5 e672 0019 ef08 a22f 0000 0000  .-...r...../....
    0x0020:  a002 16d0 f0df 0000 0204 05b4 0402 080a  ................
    0x0030:  b47c e4b4 0000 0000 0103 0305            .|..........
13:24:00.771272 IP mailer.xxx.com.smtp > 173-45-233-xxx.static.cloud-ips.com.58994: S 1790950084:1790950084(0) ack 4010320432 win 5792 <mss 1460,sackOK,timestamp 3171819547 3028083892,nop,wscale 5>
    0x0000:  4500 003c 0000 4000 4006 0b60 ad2d ebd5  E..<..@.@..`.-..
    0x0010:  ad2d e92b 0019 e672 6abf bac4 ef08 a230  .-.+...rj......0
    0x0020:  a012 16a0 ee50 0000 0204 05b4 0402 080a  .....P..........
    0x0030:  bd0e 201b b47c e4b4 0103 0305            .....|......
13:24:00.771272 IP 173-45-233-xxx.static.cloud-ips.com.58994 > mailer.xxx.com.smtp: . ack 1 win 183 <nop,nop,timestamp 3028083892 3171819547>
    0x0000:  4500 0034 469c 4000 3f06 c5cb ad2d e92b  E..4F.@.?....-.+
    0x0010:  ad2d ebd5 e672 0019 ef08 a230 6abf bac5  .-...r.....0j...
    0x0020:  8010 00b7 3304 0000 0101 080a b47c e4b4  ....3........|..
    0x0030:  bd0e 201b                                ....
13:24:00.799274 IP mailer.xxx.com.smtp > 173-45-233-xxx.static.cloud-ips.com.58994: P 1:45(44) ack 1 win 181 <nop,nop,timestamp 3171819554 3028083892>
    0x0000:  4500 0060 9ade 4000 4006 705d ad2d ebd5  E..`..@.@.p].-..
    0x0010:  ad2d e92b 0019 e672 6abf bac5 ef08 a230  .-.+...rj......0
    0x0020:  8018 00b5 2faf 0000 0101 080a bd0e 2022  ..../.........."
    0x0030:  b47c e4b4 3232 3020 6d61 696c 6572 2e72  .|..220.mailer.r
    0x0040:  646e 792e 636f 6d20 4553 4d54 5020 506f  dny.com.ESMTP.Po
    0x0050:  7374 6669 7820 2855 6275 6e74 7529 0d0a  stfix.(Ubuntu)..
13:24:00.799274 IP 173-45-233-xxx.static.cloud-ips.com.58994 > mailer.xxx.com.smtp: . ack 45 win 183 <nop,nop,timestamp 3028083900 3171819554>
    0x0000:  4500 0034 469d 4000 3f06 c5ca ad2d e92b  E..4F.@.?....-.+
    0x0010:  ad2d ebd5 e672 0019 ef08 a230 6abf baf1  .-...r.....0j...
    0x0020:  8010 00b7 32c9 0000 0101 080a b47c e4bc  ....2........|..
    0x0030:  bd0e 2022                                ..."
13:24:00.799274 IP 173-45-233-xxx.static.cloud-ips.com.58994 > mailer.xxx.com.smtp: P 1:17(16) ack 45 win 183 <nop,nop,timestamp 3028083900 3171819554>
    0x0000:  4500 0044 469e 4000 3f06 c5b9 ad2d e92b  E..DF.@.?....-.+
    0x0010:  ad2d ebd5 e672 0019 ef08 a230 6abf baf1  .-...r.....0j...
    0x0020:  8018 00b7 c6ef 0000 0101 080a b47c e4bc  .............|..
    0x0030:  bd0e 2022 4548 4c4f 206c 6f63 616c 686f  ..."EHLO.localho
    0x0040:  7374 0d0a                                st..
13:24:00.799274 IP mailer.xxx.com.smtp > 173-45-233-xxx.static.cloud-ips.com.58994: . ack 17 win 181 <nop,nop,timestamp 3171819554 3028083900>
    0x0000:  4500 0034 9adf 4000 4006 7088 ad2d ebd5  E..4..@.@.p..-..
    0x0010:  ad2d e92b 0019 e672 6abf baf1 ef08 a240  .-.+...rj......@
    0x0020:  8010 00b5 32bb 0000 0101 080a bd0e 2022  ....2.........."
    0x0030:  b47c e4bc                                .|..
13:24:00.799274 IP mailer.xxx.com.smtp > 173-45-233-xxx.static.cloud-ips.com.58994: P 45:213(168) ack 17 win 181 <nop,nop,timestamp 3171819554 3028083900>
    0x0000:  4500 00dc 9ae0 4000 4006 6fdf ad2d ebd5  E.....@.@.o..-..
    0x0010:  ad2d e92b 0019 e672 6abf baf1 ef08 a240  .-.+...rj......@
    0x0020:  8018 00b5 302b 0000 0101 080a bd0e 2022  ....0+........."
    0x0030:  b47c e4bc 3235 302d 6d61 696c 6572 2e72  .|..250-mailer.r
    0x0040:  646e 792e 636f 6d0d 0a32 3530 2d50 4950  dny.com..250-PIP
    0x0050:  454c 494e 494e 470d 0a32 3530 2d53 495a  ELINING..250-SIZ
    0x0060:  4520 3130 3234 3030 3030 0d0a 3235 302d  E.10240000..250-
    0x0070:  5652 4659 0d0a 3235 302d 4554 524e 0d0a  VRFY..250-ETRN..
    0x0080:  3235 302d 5354 4152 5454 4c53 0d0a 3235  250-STARTTLS..25
    0x0090:  302d 4155 5448 2044 4947 4553 542d 4d44  0-AUTH.DIGEST-MD
    0x00a0:  3520 4352 414d 2d4d 4435 0d0a 3235 302d  5.CRAM-MD5..250-
    0x00b0:  454e 4841 4e43 4544 5354 4154 5553 434f  ENHANCEDSTATUSCO
    0x00c0:  4445 530d 0a32 3530 2d38 4249 544d 494d  DES..250-8BITMIM
    0x00d0:  450d 0a32 3530 2044 534e 0d0a            E..250.DSN..
13:24:00.799274 IP 173-45-233-xxx.static.cloud-ips.com.58994 > mailer.xxx.com.smtp: P 17:27(10) ack 213 win 216 <nop,nop,timestamp 3028083900 3171819554>
    0x0000:  4500 003e 469f 4000 3f06 c5be ad2d e92b  E..>F.@.?....-.+
    0x0010:  ad2d ebd5 e672 0019 ef08 a240 6abf bb99  .-...r.....@j...
    0x0020:  8018 00d8 ef85 0000 0101 080a b47c e4bc  .............|..
    0x0030:  bd0e 2022 5354 4152 5454 4c53 0d0a       ..."STARTTLS..
13:24:00.803274 IP mailer.xxx.com.smtp > 173-45-233-xxx.static.cloud-ips.com.58994: P 213:243(30) ack 27 win 181 <nop,nop,timestamp 3171819555 3028083900>
    0x0000:  4500 0052 9ae1 4000 4006 7068 ad2d ebd5  E..R..@.@.ph.-..
    0x0010:  ad2d e92b 0019 e672 6abf bb99 ef08 a24a  .-.+...rj......J
    0x0020:  8018 00b5 2fa1 0000 0101 080a bd0e 2023  ..../..........#
    0x0030:  b47c e4bc 3232 3020 322e 302e 3020 5265  .|..220.2.0.0.Re
    0x0040:  6164 7920 746f 2073 7461 7274 2054 4c53  ady.to.start.TLS
    0x0050:  0d0a                                     ..
13:24:00.803274 IP 173-45-233-xxx.static.cloud-ips.com.58994 > mailer.xxx.com.smtp: P 27:114(87) ack 243 win 216 <nop,nop,timestamp 3028083900 3171819555>
    0x0000:  4500 008b 46a0 4000 3f06 c570 ad2d e92b  E...F.@.?..p.-.+
    0x0010:  ad2d ebd5 e672 0019 ef08 a24a 6abf bbb7  .-...r.....Jj...
    0x0020:  8018 00d8 7178 0000 0101 080a b47c e4bc  ....qx.......|..
    0x0030:  bd0e 2023 1603 0100 5201 0000 4e03 014b  ...#....R...N..K
    0x0040:  5f33 40e4 c7ef 1dc5 f087 941d ce4a 821f  _3@..........J..
    0x0050:  97d7 c6a9 c23b 6e04 c887 5772 9501 6500  .....;n...Wr..e.
    0x0060:  0026 0039 0038 0035 0016 0013 000a 0033  .&.9.8.5.......3
    0x0070:  0032 002f 0005 0004 0015 0012 0009 0014  .2./............
    0x0080:  0011 0008 0006 0003 0201 00              ...........
13:24:00.811275 IP mailer.xxx.com.smtp > 173-45-233-xxx.static.cloud-ips.com.58994: P 243:1179(936) ack 114 win 181 <nop,nop,timestamp 3171819557 3028083900>
    0x0000:  4500 03dc 9ae2 4000 4006 6cdd ad2d ebd5  E.....@.@.l..-..
    0x0010:  ad2d e92b 0019 e672 6abf bbb7 ef08 a2a1  .-.+...rj.......
    0x0020:  8018 00b5 332b 0000 0101 080a bd0e 2025  ....3+.........%
    0x0030:  b47c e4bc 1603 0100 4a02 0000 4603 014b  .|......J...F..K
    0x0040:  5f33 4091 f005 3620 7505 284f 8220 37b7  _3@...6.u.(O..7.
    0x0050:  d1ad 75e0 4528 094d 976c 6920 e0fa 2b20  ..u.E(.M.li...+.
    0x0060:  987e a3d7 9790 a336 8114 df7e 2caa f078  .~.....6...~,..x
    0x0070:  a5d3 b01d 5bd2 2da7 5b1f 7ebf e685 9eba  ....[.-.[.~.....
    0x0080:  0039 0116 0301 01b9 0b00 01b5 0001 b200  .9..............
    0x0090:  01af 3082 01ab 3082 0114 0209 009b e749  ..0...0........I
    0x00a0:  3655 ce91 0b30 0d06 092a 8648 86f7 0d01  6U...0...*.H....
    0x00b0:  0105 0500 301a 3118 3016 0603 5504 0313  ....0.1.0...U...
    0x00c0:  0f6d 6169 6c65 722e 7264 6e79 2e63 6f6d  .mailer.xxx.com
    0x00d0:  301e 170d 3039 3039 3031 3232 3335 3339  0...090901223539
    0x00e0:  5a17 0d31 3930 3833 3032 3233 3533 395a  Z..190830223539Z
    0x00f0:  301a 3118 3016 0603 5504 0313 0f6d 6169  0.1.0...U....mai
    0x0100:  6c65 722e 7264 6e79 2e63 6f6d 3081 9f30  ler.rdny.com0..0
    0x0110:  0d06 092a 8648 86f7 0d01 0101 0500 0381  ...*.H..........
    0x0120:  8d00 3081 8902 8181 00f4 1cb3 26f0 bf56  ..0.........&..V
    0x0130:  3ad5 065a 5fdb e6ee 10a6 cbee da40 1608  :..Z_........@..
    0x0140:  e2d7 e305 7d3e 1f6f ff85 9628 9bf9 5b22  ....}>.o...(..["
    0x0150:  3eae 0118 c5be 7c86 d059 d129 27e8 634f  >.....|..Y.)'.cO
    0x0160:  6cd5 c4a0 7010 766d 749d 56e7 280c a8a7  l...p.vmt.V.(...
    0x0170:  d1f7 7943 4583 6cd8 1f4a 9349 6528 b0b6  ..yCE.l..J.Ie(..
    0x0180:  3b54 ff3c da4b b84c 2bf5 a367 de07 90e8  ;T.<.K.L+..g....
    0x0190:  b68e 1a5c d5e1 537b 2d94 a6fa e44f ea6b  ...\..S{-....O.k
    0x01a0:  5d32 7b28 c2bf a942 ad02 0301 0001 300d  ]2{(...B......0.
    0x01b0:  0609 2a86 4886 f70d 0101 0505 0003 8181  ..*.H...........
    0x01c0:  0007 ce68 42a8 41b8 b84e e820 0d87 c080  ...hB.A..N......
    0x01d0:  f6cd e1f5 4ebc b007 999e 422c cfb5 c7f8  ....N.....B,....
    0x01e0:  bd09 2ff9 bc45 c1e5 d659 9f28 d6ff 3471  ../..E...Y.(..4q
    0x01f0:  fef8 1771 a266 524f 4423 e9f4 cfcc b90c  ...q.fROD#......
    0x0200:  97f0 37b7 956f f8fa 5ab8 26d3 95cf 6f55  ..7..o..Z.&...oU
    0x0210:  93ff 99f3 5b7a 5025 e8da c5fc 5e24 308c  ....[zP%....^$0.
    0x0220:  d049 461d 5437 14dc 7207 6854 8226 2b84  .IF.T7..r.hT.&+.
    0x0230:  ac02 94f3 3a28 6eb4 7cb1 e38c e147 7251  ....:(n.|....GrQ
    0x0240:  eb16 0301 018d 0c00 0189 0080 b0fe b4cf  ................
    0x0250:  d455 07e7 cc88 590d 1726 c50c a54a 9223  .U....Y..&...J.#
    0x0260:  8178 da88 aa4c 1306 bf5d 2f9e bc96 b851  .x...L...]/....Q
    0x0270:  009d 0c0d 75ad fd3b b17e 714f 3f91 5414  ....u..;.~qO?.T.
    0x0280:  44b8 3025 1ceb df72 9c4c f189 0d68 3f94  D.0%...r.L...h?.
    0x0290:  8ea4 fb76 8918 b291 1690 0199 668c 5381  ...v........f.S.
    0x02a0:  4e27 3d99 e75a 7aaf d5ec e27e faed 0118  N'=..Zz....~....
    0x02b0:  c278 2559 065c 39f6 cd49 54af c1b1 ea4a  .x%Y.\9..IT....J
    0x02c0:  f953 d0df 6daf d493 e7ba ae9b 0001 0200  .S..m...........
    0x02d0:  804e a0d2 7d52 9786 ec5a 306e 1bfc d81e  .N..}R...Z0n....
    0x02e0:  e762 6e94 c222 91b5 013f 0da6 4dfb 452a  .bn.."...?..M.E*
    0x02f0:  b931 62d4 caf7 a8ac 279d 578c b32a e7e1  .1b.....'.W..*..
    0x0300:  1e47 f159 181d fb99 b839 9854 76c1 1d87  .G.Y.....9.Tv...
    0x0310:  7796 bddc a86a d3cc 17e7 4ac0 bbc9 a1d1  w....j....J.....
    0x0320:  bc41 d42c 75d5 97f7 a17e 23aa 07fc d434  .A.,u....~#....4
    0x0330:  ee77 8633 a0e6 efc5 5257 4374 2b6b 5bd7  .w.3....RWCt+k[.
    0x0340:  ca5e 591d 7ddf 3e26 d70d 46b2 082e 6d75  .^Y.}.>&..F...mu
    0x0350:  7a00 8030 0f97 963b 61b9 b2db 9e20 06fa  z..0...;a.......
    0x0360:  3045 06b7 09ef faeb 0b65 95f2 6724 b9b7  0E.......e..g$..
    0x0370:  a7e9 b922 90d0 5c8a 7a73 65b7 1996 11ed  ..."..\.zse.....
    0x0380:  f209 fd3a eec1 2da7 a572 b272 0bd3 fb05  ...:..-..r.r....
    0x0390:  7013 5e79 37b2 e17d d59a bcca f2cb 0468  p.^y7..}.......h
    0x03a0:  5650 79ae 84c5 f602 007b e0c4 7988 b48d  VPy......{..y...
    0x03b0:  ffa9 6a5d 3b79 cca4 d33b 3660 1503 d986  ..j];y...;6`....
    0x03c0:  c553 b28e 1f01 9ca3 1e0a 3805 ac29 35c8  .S........8..)5.
    0x03d0:  467e 2f16 0301 0004 0e00 0000            F~/.........
13:24:00.851277 IP 173-45-233-xxx.static.cloud-ips.com.58994 > mailer.xxx.com.smtp: . ack 1179 win 275 <nop,nop,timestamp 3028083913 3171819557>
    0x0000:  4500 0034 46a1 4000 3f06 c5c6 ad2d e92b  E..4F.@.?....-.+
    0x0010:  ad2d ebd5 e672 0019 ef08 a2a1 6abf bf5f  .-...r......j.._
    0x0020:  8010 0113 2d7e 0000 0101 080a b47c e4c9  ....-~.......|..
    0x0030:  bd0e 2025                                ...%
13:24:00.851277 IP 173-45-233-xxx.static.cloud-ips.com.58994 > mailer.xxx.com.smtp: P 114:312(198) ack 1179 win 275 <nop,nop,timestamp 3028083913 3171819557>
    0x0000:  4500 00fa 46a2 4000 3f06 c4ff ad2d e92b  E...F.@.?....-.+
    0x0010:  ad2d ebd5 e672 0019 ef08 a2a1 6abf bf5f  .-...r......j.._
    0x0020:  8018 0113 3b49 0000 0101 080a b47c e4c9  ....;I.......|..
    0x0030:  bd0e 2025 1603 0100 8610 0000 8200 8008  ...%............
    0x0040:  ccdb 3530 85ee 026f b2da c713 e572 730f  ..50...o.....rs.
    0x0050:  b808 1641 e85b bef2 ec97 4bb2 4b3a 2371  ...A.[....K.K:#q
    0x0060:  34b9 ec27 9f8a bde4 2f5f 58a7 a6b6 4510  4..'..../_X...E.
    0x0070:  bd69 434a 1c3c 42fb bd54 de39 9052 dd9d  .iCJ.<B..T.9.R..
    0x0080:  bf0f 57a6 1f30 3ef4 1295 ec4f 75eb 06da  ..W..0>....Ou...
    0x0090:  ebe3 fcd7 2e64 cfd1 77a8 9eef e856 d197  .....d..w....V..
    0x00a0:  90de 4108 2dd6 45d8 96fb 0c2b 3185 b23e  ..A.-.E....+1..>
    0x00b0:  81f6 e931 455f 3657 78a9 793d 1b95 4f14  ...1E_6Wx.y=..O.
    0x00c0:  0301 0001 0116 0301 0030 ff4c 564d fa2b  .........0.LVM.+
    0x00d0:  5323 8a16 fd11 77dc 1b74 5385 0cd2 a2ef  S#....w..tS.....
    0x00e0:  315c 39ec c63a 8cdc 2aa4 8abd 439e 96e2  1\9..:..*...C...
    0x00f0:  0a4d 3ef7 9bbc 5726 7310                 .M>...W&s.
13:24:00.875278 IP mailer.xxx.com.smtp > 173-45-233-xxx.static.cloud-ips.com.58994: P 1179:1238(59) ack 312 win 215 <nop,nop,timestamp 3171819573 3028083913>
    0x0000:  4500 006f 9ae3 4000 4006 7049 ad2d ebd5  E..o..@.@.pI.-..
    0x0010:  ad2d e92b 0019 e672 6abf bf5f ef08 a367  .-.+...rj.._...g
    0x0020:  8018 00d7 2fbe 0000 0101 080a bd0e 2035  ..../..........5
    0x0030:  b47c e4c9 1403 0100 0101 1603 0100 304b  .|............0K
    0x0040:  4480 86f3 7c75 98fd 845a a0cc 7d1c 6c5a  D...|u...Z..}.lZ
    0x0050:  d742 c43e c2a1 94b6 ca03 42fb 00ff 6d27  .B.>......B...m'
    0x0060:  10b4 f834 51c1 1c12 0744 0784 11ce 82    ...4Q....D.....
13:24:00.879279 IP 173-45-233-xxx.static.cloud-ips.com.58994 > mailer.xxx.com.smtp: . ack 1238 win 275 <nop,nop,timestamp 3028083919 3171819573>
    0x0000:  4500 0034 46a3 4000 3f06 c5c4 ad2d e92b  E..4F.@.?....-.+
    0x0010:  ad2d ebd5 e672 0019 ef08 a367 6abf bf9a  .-...r.....gj...
    0x0020:  8010 0113 2c67 0000 0101 080a b47c e4cf  ....,g.......|..
    0x0030:  bd0e 2035                                ...5
13:24:00.879279 IP 173-45-233-xxx.static.cloud-ips.com.58994 > mailer.xxx.com.smtp: P 312:365(53) ack 1238 win 275 <nop,nop,timestamp 3028083919 3171819573>
    0x0000:  4500 0069 46a4 4000 3f06 c58e ad2d e92b  E..iF.@.?....-.+
    0x0010:  ad2d ebd5 e672 0019 ef08 a367 6abf bf9a  .-...r.....gj...
    0x0020:  8018 0113 711d 0000 0101 080a b47c e4cf  ....q........|..
    0x0030:  bd0e 2035 1703 0100 3029 8cbe 29be 7304  ...5....0)..).s.
    0x0040:  9f4b dca8 b447 97f6 b5c8 e7a2 c081 3c05  .K...G........<.
    0x0050:  d944 e3c6 c056 3bb3 2be8 c3f8 cfeb 7f29  .D...V;.+......)
    0x0060:  685d 0ba5 488e 0c9d 26                   h]..H...&
13:24:00.879279 IP mailer.xxx.com.smtp > 173-45-233-xxx.static.cloud-ips.com.58994: P 1238:1403(165) ack 365 win 215 <nop,nop,timestamp 3171819574 3028083919>
    0x0000:  4500 00d9 9ae4 4000 4006 6fde ad2d ebd5  E.....@.@.o..-..
    0x0010:  ad2d e92b 0019 e672 6abf bf9a ef08 a39c  .-.+...rj.......
    0x0020:  8018 00d7 3028 0000 0101 080a bd0e 2036  ....0(.........6
    0x0030:  b47c e4cf 1703 0100 a059 f2fd 972c 83bb  .|.......Y...,..
    0x0040:  b0ed 652c 8460 a90f fe52 eb8a 71c5 1bfb  ..e,.`...R..q...
    0x0050:  35ad 5adf e049 9293 4906 19bb 65f2 be7c  5.Z..I..I...e..|
    0x0060:  7541 43e4 cf8f 05f4 6fab 2dbd b934 5576  uAC.....o.-..4Uv
    0x0070:  e76e 32e6 8b6e 3954 3e0f 361f 9190 0105  .n2..n9T>.6.....
    0x0080:  0662 370b 20d0 48a4 4262 b1c0 8ea4 9ed4  .b7...H.Bb......
    0x0090:  7dca a0dd b901 66a2 ba23 812f e686 fdf3  }.....f..#./....
    0x00a0:  4b84 6017 5c5b e4be b6b6 7cd0 8f35 20df  K.`.\[....|..5..
    0x00b0:  8fd6 3faf 6557 002a f7dc 1ada af51 8a7f  ..?.eW.*.....Q..
    0x00c0:  6b37 fee6 4e5b aa85 1470 18b3 bf43 f594  k7..N[...p...C..
    0x00d0:  046a c7fd e8d7 3a2c 48                   .j....:,H
13:24:00.879279 IP 173-45-233-xxx.static.cloud-ips.com.58994 > mailer.xxx.com.smtp: P 365:418(53) ack 1403 win 333 <nop,nop,timestamp 3028083920 3171819574>
    0x0000:  4500 0069 46a5 4000 3f06 c58d ad2d e92b  E..iF.@.?....-.+
    0x0010:  ad2d ebd5 e672 0019 ef08 a39c 6abf c03f  .-...r......j..?
    0x0020:  8018 014d 29cc 0000 0101 080a b47c e4d0  ...M)........|..
    0x0030:  bd0e 2036 1703 0100 3074 085e cf4b 984b  ...6....0t.^.K.K
    0x0040:  2560 362f a49c 10e5 18f2 5ab5 076c 09ab  %`6/......Z..l..
    0x0050:  b570 734f 622e ae8c 366d f7bb 910a 5e95  .psOb...6m....^.
    0x0060:  5d02 a415 f464 594a 0d                   ]....dYJ.
13:24:00.879279 IP mailer.xxx.com.smtp > 173-45-233-xxx.static.cloud-ips.com.58994: P 1403:1456(53) ack 418 win 215 <nop,nop,timestamp 3171819574 3028083920>
    0x0000:  4500 0069 9ae5 4000 4006 704d ad2d ebd5  E..i..@.@.pM.-..
    0x0010:  ad2d e92b 0019 e672 6abf c03f ef08 a3d1  .-.+...rj..?....
    0x0020:  8018 00d7 2fb8 0000 0101 080a bd0e 2036  ..../..........6
    0x0030:  b47c e4d0 1703 0100 3043 6cf7 3196 f6ef  .|......0Cl.1...
    0x0040:  e759 8309 3636 0ea0 e215 bb9e 6399 7cb3  .Y..66......c.|.
    0x0050:  bfaa 9251 f1d4 eae0 02fb 6199 349a 92e1  ...Q......a.4...
    0x0060:  ff13 6096 18cb a366 da                   ..`....f.
13:24:00.895279 IP 173-45-233-xxx.static.cloud-ips.com.58994 > mailer.xxx.com.smtp: P 418:487(69) ack 1456 win 333 <nop,nop,timestamp 3028083924 3171819574>
    0x0000:  4500 0079 46a6 4000 3f06 c57c ad2d e92b  E..yF.@.?..|.-.+
    0x0010:  ad2d ebd5 e672 0019 ef08 a3d1 6abf c074  .-...r......j..t
    0x0020:  8018 014d f037 0000 0101 080a b47c e4d4  ...M.7.......|..
    0x0030:  bd0e 2036 1703 0100 4077 9651 35a8 076e  ...6....@w.Q5..n
    0x0040:  052b 15a0 c757 891a 57c6 5aca 705d 7de9  .+...W..W.Z.p]}.
    0x0050:  f02d 6ba7 8bce 9304 48e7 0f7f 0383 18a3  .-k.....H.......
    0x0060:  ae04 e8fa 9e3f 1539 12d1 9a97 5dad 2980  .....?.9....].).
    0x0070:  4c92 b42d 59d3 1d90 1c                   L..-Y....
13:24:00.895279 IP mailer.xxx.com.smtp > 173-45-233-xxx.static.cloud-ips.com.58994: P 1456:1493(37) ack 487 win 215 <nop,nop,timestamp 3171819578 3028083924>
    0x0000:  4500 0059 9ae6 4000 4006 705c ad2d ebd5  E..Y..@.@.p\.-..
    0x0010:  ad2d e92b 0019 e672 6abf c074 ef08 a416  .-.+...rj..t....
    0x0020:  8018 00d7 2fa8 0000 0101 080a bd0e 203a  ..../..........:
    0x0030:  b47c e4d4 1703 0100 2094 10b1 8bd5 a7a9  .|..............
    0x0040:  5b97 9a41 0eae 5874 8b94 f69b b658 69a4  [..A..Xt.....Xi.
    0x0050:  254e 19f1 d47d e608 6b                   %N...}..k
13:24:00.899280 IP 173-45-233-xxx.static.cloud-ips.com.58994 > mailer.xxx.com.smtp: P 487:540(53) ack 1493 win 333 <nop,nop,timestamp 3028083924 3171819578>
    0x0000:  4500 0069 46a7 4000 3f06 c58b ad2d e92b  E..iF.@.?....-.+
    0x0010:  ad2d ebd5 e672 0019 ef08 a416 6abf c099  .-...r......j...
    0x0020:  8018 014d 5282 0000 0101 080a b47c e4d4  ...MR........|..
    0x0030:  bd0e 203a 1703 0100 304d e9aa 5e23 0557  ...:....0M..^#.W
    0x0040:  81fd 8d07 f103 bbb7 8468 ee3d dce0 0956  .........h.=...V
    0x0050:  eb8f b10e a7e2 07ee 848e 64aa c011 cdc3  ..........d.....
    0x0060:  96bc 5bba 634b d361 41                   ..[.cK.aA
13:24:00.903280 IP mailer.xxx.com.smtp > 173-45-233-xxx.static.cloud-ips.com.58994: P 1493:1530(37) ack 540 win 215 <nop,nop,timestamp 3171819580 3028083924>
    0x0000:  4500 0059 9ae7 4000 4006 705b ad2d ebd5  E..Y..@.@.p[.-..
    0x0010:  ad2d e92b 0019 e672 6abf c099 ef08 a44b  .-.+...rj......K
    0x0020:  8018 00d7 2fa8 0000 0101 080a bd0e 203c  ..../..........<
    0x0030:  b47c e4d4 1703 0100 20d6 5aae 1e65 8537  .|........Z..e.7
    0x0040:  975d d8f0 f76d aefe 6459 f51b 1b1c 292b  .]...m..dY....)+
    0x0050:  0f5a 285f 2091 b55c 74                   .Z(_...\t
13:24:00.903280 IP 173-45-233-xxx.static.cloud-ips.com.58994 > mailer.xxx.com.smtp: P 540:593(53) ack 1530 win 333 <nop,nop,timestamp 3028083926 3171819580>
    0x0000:  4500 0069 46a8 4000 3f06 c58a ad2d e92b  E..iF.@.?....-.+
    0x0010:  ad2d ebd5 e672 0019 ef08 a44b 6abf c0be  .-...r.....Kj...
    0x0020:  8018 014d a614 0000 0101 080a b47c e4d6  ...M.........|..
    0x0030:  bd0e 203c 1703 0100 3067 4f03 ddcf 7dd6  ...<....0gO...}.
    0x0040:  e8e7 a29f e0c0 b4c5 33f0 a7e7 f9c5 e777  ........3......w
    0x0050:  3f8e 16f2 a543 7be6 c6a2 ec4f 617e a3e8  ?....C{....Oa~..
    0x0060:  8cc5 40bc e0ab a95b 2b                   ..@....[+
13:24:00.903280 IP mailer.xxx.com.smtp > 173-45-233-xxx.static.cloud-ips.com.58994: P 1530:1599(69) ack 593 win 215 <nop,nop,timestamp 3171819580 3028083926>
    0x0000:  4500 0079 9ae8 4000 4006 703a ad2d ebd5  E..y..@.@.p:.-..
    0x0010:  ad2d e92b 0019 e672 6abf c0be ef08 a480  .-.+...rj.......
    0x0020:  8018 00d7 2fc8 0000 0101 080a bd0e 203c  ..../..........<
    0x0030:  b47c e4d6 1703 0100 40b3 584e 9cc9 32df  .|......@.XN..2.
    0x0040:  e8ed 632f 9f99 3218 802d 895a 94b0 77bb  ..c/..2..-.Z..w.
    0x0050:  ff59 0d35 2fd9 ffe5 72a3 3897 8eb3 9391  .Y.5/...r.8.....
    0x0060:  c9ea 183d b36e 8a07 cfbf c547 b8ce f037  ...=.n.....G...7
    0x0070:  468a 214f 6c38 2277 08                   F.!Ol8"w.
13:24:00.903280 IP 173-45-233-xxx.static.cloud-ips.com.58994 > mailer.xxx.com.smtp: P 593:902(309) ack 1599 win 333 <nop,nop,timestamp 3028083926 3171819580>
    0x0000:  4500 0169 46a9 4000 3f06 c489 ad2d e92b  E..iF.@.?....-.+
    0x0010:  ad2d ebd5 e672 0019 ef08 a480 6abf c103  .-...r......j...
    0x0020:  8018 014d 8dd1 0000 0101 080a b47c e4d6  ...M.........|..
    0x0030:  bd0e 203c 1703 0101 307b b4db 002a 5040  ...<....0{...*P@
    0x0040:  761a 6738 9d40 0e8a e925 2c64 de46 c157  v.g8.@...%,d.F.W
    0x0050:  1d30 30dc 5861 edf0 d47b 5c62 bb94 a05e  .00.Xa...{\b...^
    0x0060:  f0e6 4e02 4ffd 1001 c6a2 4c08 907a d62f  ..N.O.....L..z./
    0x0070:  fb03 9059 1f41 cd37 7953 a2ea 67c8 e785  ...Y.A.7yS..g...
    0x0080:  9437 cb32 5052 f46b b134 0db8 1873 b3a6  .7.2PR.k.4...s..
    0x0090:  d404 0e17 fc65 865e 31ab f5aa a793 4b0e  .....e.^1.....K.
    0x00a0:  5264 deb1 7d35 ccb0 4691 8d44 787f 7e82  Rd..}5..F..Dx.~.
    0x00b0:  d731 5aef 5176 4ec5 4afe f14a af28 3fcf  .1Z.QvN.J..J.(?.
    0x00c0:  7da5 399e f6b5 c450 8cca 7439 e690 429c  }.9....P..t9..B.
    0x00d0:  54b2 51b5 a28e 8293 3da8 6cc6 fcb5 179c  T.Q.....=.l.....
    0x00e0:  1e11 58da 50c9 ca8f e217 4b8a 9dd4 bf98  ..X.P.....K.....
    0x00f0:  96f3 80b8 264a ad1a 89a7 d29b b284 7346  ....&J........sF
    0x0100:  fdf8 c168 f05c 12da f7a9 a14b e55e fc97  ...h.\.....K.^..
    0x0110:  01c5 d999 a1ea ee37 5306 4b65 0373 497a  .......7S.Ke.sIz
    0x0120:  6f25 cbe0 6a46 cacb 0da5 bca0 51a9 43d3  o%..jF......Q.C.
    0x0130:  fb5f 4a60 d0fb 21fc 021e 82f6 791f 2d8b  ._J`..!.....y.-.
    0x0140:  5011 94d2 6183 9956 5198 33d3 8a5c c6dd  P...a..VQ.3..\..
    0x0150:  722f 18cc 3980 1281 6192 6f5c b1d0 bebe  r/..9...a.o\....
    0x0160:  f854 f7dd b508 8732 8b                   .T.....2.
13:24:00.927281 IP mailer.xxx.com.smtp > 173-45-233-xxx.static.cloud-ips.com.58994: P 1599:1668(69) ack 902 win 248 <nop,nop,timestamp 3171819586 3028083926>
    0x0000:  4500 0079 9ae9 4000 4006 7039 ad2d ebd5  E..y..@.@.p9.-..
    0x0010:  ad2d e92b 0019 e672 6abf c103 ef08 a5b5  .-.+...rj.......
    0x0020:  8018 00f8 2fc8 0000 0101 080a bd0e 2042  ..../..........B
    0x0030:  b47c e4d6 1703 0100 407b 07ad 999f 67bf  .|......@{....g.
    0x0040:  9447 fb2d 0c0a 0378 c513 a982 4c09 fd7a  .G.-...x....L..z
    0x0050:  51b3 728e 3687 2661 0cbb b554 f227 4f54  Q.r.6.&a...T.'OT
    0x0060:  8b3b 65aa 34ba b71a 9a2e 6c23 54f4 8917  .;e.4.....l#T...
    0x0070:  9f64 1fef 6de8 692f a8                   .d..m.i/.
13:24:00.927281 IP 173-45-233-xxx.static.cloud-ips.com.58994 > mailer.xxx.com.smtp: P 902:955(53) ack 1668 win 333 <nop,nop,timestamp 3028083932 3171819586>
    0x0000:  4500 0069 46aa 4000 3f06 c588 ad2d e92b  E..iF.@.?....-.+
    0x0010:  ad2d ebd5 e672 0019 ef08 a5b5 6abf c148  .-...r......j..H
    0x0020:  8018 014d 72ee 0000 0101 080a b47c e4dc  ...Mr........|..
    0x0030:  bd0e 2042 1703 0100 309d d4aa d0a4 4d47  ...B....0.....MG
    0x0040:  edea 624a 2df2 8ac8 99e4 65c0 724c 17f0  ..bJ-.....e.rL..
    0x0050:  4745 481f 7906 d143 a6c0 75e9 767e 2b9b  GEH.y..C..u.v~+.
    0x0060:  d7b9 228f e937 30ef 3a                   .."..70.:
13:24:00.927281 IP mailer.xxx.com.smtp > 173-45-233-xxx.static.cloud-ips.com.58994: P 1668:1721(53) ack 955 win 248 <nop,nop,timestamp 3171819586 3028083932>
    0x0000:  4500 0069 9aea 4000 4006 7048 ad2d ebd5  E..i..@.@.pH.-..
    0x0010:  ad2d e92b 0019 e672 6abf c148 ef08 a5ea  .-.+...rj..H....
    0x0020:  8018 00f8 2fb8 0000 0101 080a bd0e 2042  ..../..........B
    0x0030:  b47c e4dc 1703 0100 30eb 7d04 85a1 2411  .|......0.}...$.
    0x0040:  eb9f 9abc 068b d36d 1c21 1e1e 4857 bce7  .......m.!..HW..
    0x0050:  eb7e 5980 f3b4 61c7 bd76 00bc 3165 a980  .~Y...a..v..1e..
    0x0060:  1ca3 5c67 a502 3b73 ea                   ..\g..;s.
13:24:00.927281 IP mailer.xxx.com.smtp > 173-45-233-xxx.static.cloud-ips.com.58994: F 1721:1721(0) ack 955 win 248 <nop,nop,timestamp 3171819586 3028083932>
    0x0000:  4500 0034 9aeb 4000 4006 707c ad2d ebd5  E..4..@.@.p|.-..
    0x0010:  ad2d e92b 0019 e672 6abf c17d ef08 a5ea  .-.+...rj..}....
    0x0020:  8011 00f8 2801 0000 0101 080a bd0e 2042  ....(..........B
    0x0030:  b47c e4dc                                .|..
13:24:00.927281 IP 173-45-233-xxx.static.cloud-ips.com.58994 > mailer.xxx.com.smtp: P 955:992(37) ack 1721 win 333 <nop,nop,timestamp 3028083932 3171819586>
    0x0000:  4500 0059 46ab 4000 3f06 c597 ad2d e92b  E..YF.@.?....-.+
    0x0010:  ad2d ebd5 e672 0019 ef08 a5ea 6abf c17d  .-...r......j..}
    0x0020:  8018 014d e21e 0000 0101 080a b47c e4dc  ...M.........|..
    0x0030:  bd0e 2042 1503 0100 2067 29a7 644c ff8f  ...B.....g).dL..
    0x0040:  5abc 3b17 f77b f381 7ab7 d718 0e2a 535b  Z.;..{..z....*S[
    0x0050:  91a0 6a11 0ea8 35f2 0d                   ..j...5..
13:24:00.927281 IP mailer.xxx.com.smtp > 173-45-233-xxx.static.cloud-ips.com.58994: R 1790951805:1790951805(0) win 0
    0x0000:  4500 0028 0000 4000 4006 0b74 ad2d ebd5  E..(..@.@..t.-..
    0x0010:  ad2d e92b 0019 e672 6abf c17d 0000 0000  .-.+...rj..}....
    0x0020:  5004 0000 6dbb 0000                      P...m...
13:24:00.927281 IP 173-45-233-xxx.static.cloud-ips.com.58994 > mailer.xxx.com.smtp: F 992:992(0) ac
```

Comment: This sounds like a code problem, since the client is initiating the disconnect.  Try stackoverflow.

Comment: I've already posted a question there, but they're leaning towards a configuration problem. The code works--verbatim--on another server, so why shouldn't it work on this server?

Comment: Because your code is initiating an SMTP transaction and could be borking at any number of things. The chances this is a postfix problem is very very slim in my experience.

Post the code and your postfix configuration (postconf -n)

Comment: I understand that, but I'm at a loss to explain why this code works on every other web server except this one, which (logically) doesn't suggest to me that the problem lies with the code.  I posted those files above.

Comment: Is it conceivable that my webserver is being interpreted by Postfix as a bot? "Use "421" reply codes for botnet-related RBLs or for selected non-RBL restrictions. This causes Postfix 2.3 and later to disconnect immediately without waiting for the remote SMTP client to send a QUIT command." http://postfix.mirrorspace.org/STRESS_README.html#hangup  ????

Comment: Okay, I've now totally confirmed that my code is fine and functioning normally. If I change the parameters to use GMail instead of my Postfix server, it works flawlessly. As this same code works on several other webservers that I have access to, the problem **MUST** lie in this one particular webserver, or how Postfix interacts with this one particular webserver. What could cause this behavior in Postfix?!?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that specific webserver might have a host resolution issue.
Perhaps you put the destination IP address in `/etc/hosts`..? Or there is a MX caching issue..?

If it works on a different server it's not a code problem. The tcpdump seems to show that the mail gets accepted. Check the mailer log.

Comment: Mailer log showed nothing but the connect and immediate disconnect, when I was still having the problem. As I can't seem to replicate it, I think it is the specific webserver as well (since the code works on other servers.) I'll look into that separately.

Answer (score 1):

tcpdump -s0 -X -i eth0 port 25 and host YOUR_CLIENTPHP_IP_HERE

Comment: Posted... great, now it seems to be working. I ran into this before, where it would sporadically work, then fail later. Can you tell if anything's amiss by the tcpdump? I should clarify and say that the code has NOT changed.

Answer (score 0):

Mind pasting a tcpdump trace here?

tcpdump -s0 -X -i eth0 port 25

Comment: I tried doing that, but my mail relay is live, so it's getting a TON of other traffic hitting it that tcpdump is picking up too. Is there anyway to separate the hits you want from the others?

Answer (score 0):

Have you verified that php is configured correctly on the misbehaving server? i.e., are there additional restrictions set in php.ini that are different on the "bad" server versus the "good" one?

Sorry, my php-fu is weak, but if those are the only logs you're getting from postfix, my impression is that the problem is on the sending side, not the receiving one.

Failing that, I would loosen your smtpd_recipient_restrictions to see if that's not causing issues.

Comment: Compared the two ini's, they look pretty much the same. In fact, they're identical. It kinda stinks that it's working now because I can't reliably test loosening the restrictions, since they work now as-is. Might this behavior lend some credence to my thought that this might be a 421 response? (In my comment on the question)??

Comment: By default, postfix should log all of the transactions involved in the processing of the email. If it was resulting in a 421, that should be glaringly obvious in the mail log.

Comment: Yeah, I figured as much. Oh well.

Comment: The next time it fails, you can filter for your destination address with tcpdump like Borys suggested.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using cloud provider, then sometimes they are blocking outgoing SMTP traffic or limit number of outgoing connections and emails. Usually you need to submit request to remove mail limit and create reverse DNS record for your IP to domain mapping.